# Secure Server after configuration

Tags: security, vps

Recently I purchased a VPS from intovps.com, And first time I configured a fully unmanaged VPS through ssh comands.
My website is working into it, properly.
Now I just want to know how to secure it?

I started my process of configuring VPS in this way:-

Installed LAMP, phpmyadmin, restored the backup(wordpress & mysql), installed vsftpd for ftp access, added a user into FTP(user can navigate into any directory over the entire VPS, but change anything)

Now after everything, I just want to know the security steps for my VPS. I have heard from my friends that after configuring a VPS, it also needs to be configure for security. 
In VPS, I have only one user added for ssh access, which is default,and I just added one ftp user.

Now I want that the ftp added user should just navigate to the `/html` directory, where my website is installed, and has all writes to change everything

And any suggestions or tricks or steps for making server more secure?

Comment: This should be migrated to SO or SF, this isn't a question about or relating to WordPress. I've voted for close(off-topic), but if anyone with power is reading, please migrate the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this excellent [**question and answers**](https://serverfault.com/questions/212269/tips-for-securing-a-lamp-server) on Server Fault that discusses how to secure your LAMP stack.

Make sure your FTP user can only access the directories you want.

Setup [sudo](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/) to allow a non root user to run commands as root.
Lock down your ssh so that root cannot log in set

`PermitRootLogin = no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Enable [passwordless public key login](http://linux-tips.org/article/33/passwordless-ssh-setup) for ssh.
Disable [ssh password login](http://linux-tips.org/article/60/disabling-ssh-password-authentication)